# Bash Function: Unary Operator Expected error

Tags: bash

I am learning bash scripting and currently having trouble with an `if` statement inside a function. The following code returns two errors; both of which reference the `if` and `elif` conditions and say `[: 12000: unary operator expected`.

```
function calculateBonus {
    # If the sales figure is greater than 1 million, bonus is £1500
    if [ $1 >= 1000000 ]
    then
        bonus=1500
    # If greater than 100000, bonus is £750
    elif [ $1 >= 100000 ]
    then
        bonus=750
    else
        bonus=0
    fi

    # Return the bonus figure
    return $bonus
}

read sales
bonus=$(calculateBonus $sales)
```

I have tried using double square brackets, but I'm given a syntax error for some reason. Could someone explain the reason for the error above and for the syntax error when I use `[[ some_condition ]]` instead of `[ some_condition ]`.

Comment: IIRC the operators for greater equal aren't `>=` but `-ge`. Look into `man test` (`test` should be the same as `[`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function calculateBonus() {
    if (( $1 >= 1000000 )); then
        bonus=1500
    elif (( $1 >= 100000 )); then
        bonus=750
    else
        bonus=0
    fi
}

read sales
calculateBonus "$sales"
echo "Bonus is $bonus"
```

The `(())` is arithmetic evaluation.  The function sets the variable `bonus` which can be used after the function is called.  The `return` in a function does not do what you might think it does (it's an exit code).  See also [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions) about returning values from a function.

[This article](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) has a nice discussion on the various test constructs, with examples.

Comment: Thanks e0k, very comprehensive and answered another question I had

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculateBonus {
# If the sales figure is greater than 1 million, bonus is £1500
if [ $1 -ge 1000000 ]
then
    bonus=1500
# If greater than 100000, bonus is £750
elif [ $1 -ge 100000 ]
then
    bonus=750
else
    bonus=0
fi

}

read sales
calculateBonus $sales
echo $bonus
```

`-ge`=>greater than or equal to

see `man test` which is same as `[`, `help [` directs you to `man test`

`<`, `>` are used for string comparison in bash(dictionary/lexicographical order)

Note: bash also has an advanced if condition operator `[[` that has all features of `test` or `[` plus more, see `help [[`

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot that's sorted it. Separately from this; when I echo $bonus, it doesn't echo anything. Why is the return value from calculateBonus not assigned to $bonus?

Comment: In this instance yeah I can. But if I need to return a value to a variable instead of just echoing it, why would the above not work?